# How to return an Excel from disk as an HttpResponse using Django

Tags: python, django, excel

I'm using Django to write a button on my web page to support download button, I've generated the Excel (.xls) files already and they're saved on the server. I don't need to use a csv writer to write rows and columns on the fly and then return the response, however, I just wanted to pass the excel file on my disk into the response and then return the response, my function in views.py is like this:

```
def price_list_download(request):
    today = date.today()
    filename = 'test_price_list-%s.xls' % today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    response = HttpResponse(file("PATH_TO_EXCEL.xls"))
    response['Content-Type'] ='application/vnd.ms-excel'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'

    return response
```

It's able to download, however, when I tried to open the downloaded file, it pops up a banner saying: the file you are trying to open, "NAME_OF_FILE.xls" is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Do you want to open it now?...

I double checked that .xls file should be using application/vnd.ms-excel this content-type, so I'm confused that where went wrong.
When I click yes and tried to open this downloaded file, it only contains a random string (ÐÏà¡±) in row 0 column 0, the rest of the file is blank.

Any help please?
Thanks

Comment: You need to convert into json-compatible format like csv and then return it - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/outputting-csv/, http://djangotricks.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-export-data-as-excel.html, https://github.com/pyexcel/django-excel

Comment: Thanks for pointing me that link. But as that link says known constraint: Fonts, colors and charts are not supported. But I do need to have the .xls files downloaded still have one picture as the header, and all the other headers are highlighted with bold and forecolors. Also, I noticed that this pyexcel/django-excel project has tested only Django of versions 1.7.8+, however, due to various reasons, our Django has to stay at version 1.5, so I don't think this could help my situation. Is there any other way? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here's another example that might help https://assist-software.net/blog/how-export-excel-files-python-django-application

Comment: @dmitryro Thanks a lot, that examples looks really promising, but it's using Django 1.8.2, mine is 1.5, I'm not sure if this is going to create any hindrance for me, but I'm going to give it a try and let you know soon. Thanks

Comment: I just realized that this example is creating/writing to Excel on the fly, but my case is that I've the Excel file on the disk already, I certainly don't want have for loops and configure header, fonts, styles again, I only wanted to put the excel on the server into the response. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, problem solved, one of my coworkers helped me out:
I dont' need to be constrained to return an HttpResponse, instead I could just use `<a href="RELATIVE_PATH_TO_MY_FILE" type="submit"></a>` into the html button.
This way, I don't need to open the excel on the disk and read it into memory and write into an HttpResponse again. Also, it saves the work of all of the fancy headers and format that I've already generated in the Excel.

Thanks! Hope this could serve others in similar scenarios!

Comment: This is helpful but a direct answer to the original question would be good to add